# Запись и вывод данных local Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно через 10 секунд после того как пользователь ввел какой-то текст его сохранить в local Storage, а при перезагрузке страницы вывести данные из local Storage в текстовое поле. При успешной отправке формы удалить данные с local Storage.

```
   <form id="form_id" action="save.php" method="post">  
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        <br><br>
      <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5" cols="25"></textarea>
        <br><br>        
      <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Сохранить" />   
    </form> 

    <br>
      <div id="alert"></div>
   <br><br>
      <div id="preview"></div>
```

Js

```
$("#message").keyup(function() {

    setTimeout(function() {   
      var mes_value = $('#message').val();

        localStorage.setItem('local', mes_value);  // сохраняем в local Storage

        var local_value = localStorage.getItem('local');  // извлекаем из local Storage
        var local_value = local_value.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");

        $('#preview').html(local_value);  // показываем что сохранилось

        $('#alert').html("<strong>Даные Сохранено</strong>"); // показываем сообщение
        $('#alert').fadeIn().delay(1500).fadeOut(); // почему оно показывается несколько раз если должно показываться только один раз 
    }, 3000);

});

//Как при перегрузки страницы вставить данные из local Storage в текстовое поле #message; и #preview;
```

Comment: Тут на странице вы не смотрели как это организовано?

Comment: Извини не совсем понял, имеешь в виду на этом сайте ?

Comment: Да, прямо на этой странице в поле ввода ответа.

Comment: Первое. Что бы сохранить переносы строк, наверное не надо делать replace при в самой переменной, а лучше сделать replace где надо(я так понимаю Local_value)

Второе. Каждый раз при нажатии кнопки у Вас формируется новый setTimeout и никуда не исчезает, потом они все кучей срабатывают. Меняйте логику.

Comment: С переносами срок разобрался, а логикой не могу разобраться, если можешь опиши в нескольких словах.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С логикой можно сделать так. Если SetTimeout уже создан, мы храним какой-нибудь признак этого и не создаем его заново. Ну для примера через дополнительное свойство у элемента:

```
<textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5" cols="25" data-ischange="none"></textarea>

$("#message").keyup(function() {
    var message = $('#message');

    //проверяем, создан ли таймаут
    if(message.attr("data-ischange") == "none"){ 
        message.attr("data-ischange","change"); //блокируем, что бы новый не создавался
        setTimeout(function() {
            var mes_value = message.val();

            localStorage.setItem('local', mes_value); 

            var local_value = localStorage.getItem('local').replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
            $('#preview').html(local_value);  

            $('#alert').html("<strong>Данные Сохранено</strong>");
            $('#alert').fadeIn().delay(1500).fadeOut();
            message.attr("data-ischange","none"); //после отработки снимаем блокировку
        }, 3000);
    }
});
```